# Delete a user Completely in SharePoint 2010

Tags: permissions, user-controls

Is there a way that when an administrator deletes a user from a SharePoint group the user can be totally deleted?  Presently when an admin deletes a user from the group he can still see the user in the User Information List (UIL) and that's causing lot of confusion to the non-technical community administrators.  They are seeing this list because whenever they edit the current view (Detail View) they are ending up in UIL and that's confusing them.  Is there a power shell script which will delete the users in the user information list once they are deleted from the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the user from the Site Collection.  This will mark them as tp_Deleted != 0 in the UIL.  Do not remove users from the UIL manually as this will break functionality on items the user was stamped on (e.g. Workflows will fail to start if that user saved them).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd303914(v=prot.13).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the answer trevor but is there any automatic way of doing that may be through power shell

Comment: Also if you have multiple site collections you will need to delete them from each one.

Comment: See this Stackexchange comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/36421/remove-a-single-user-from-all-site-collections-in-a-web-application-using-powers