# remove and re-add user account for site collections through powershell

Tags: 2010, powershell

Having trouble find any resources for using Powershell to remove and re-add an user account for site visitors.  I have 80+ sites where I need to iterate through and remove the current visitor account and re-add it to update them to the new role provider.  Not sure what best practice is on this but was hoping I could automate this through Powershell instead of manually going to each collection and removing and re-adding the account.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of removing and re-adding you may be able to just update their accounts.

```
Move-SPUser -Identity "c:0-.f|atschoolroleprovider|parent" -NewAlias "c:0-.f|nhaschoolsauthroleprovider|parent"
```

You can use the `Get-SPUser` to get all users and then loop over them to run across multiple accounts.

Answer (score 1):

to remove a user try this one

```
######################## Start Variables ########################
$LoginName = "domain\login"
$siteURL = "http://SharePointSiteURL" #URL to any site in the web application.
######################## End Variables ########################
Clear-Host
$siteCount = 0
[system.reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("Microsoft.SharePoint")
$site = new-object microsoft.sharepoint.spsite($siteURL)
$webApp = $site.webapplication
$allSites = $webApp.sites
foreach ($site in $allSites)
{

    $web = $site.openweb()
    $web.SiteUsers.Remove($LoginName)
    $web.Dispose()
    $siteCount++
}
$site.dispose()
write-host "Updated" $siteCount "Site Collections."
```

[Remove a single user from all site collections in a web application using powershell](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/36421/remove-a-single-user-from-all-site-collections-in-a-web-application-using-powers)

for adding a user, please check this
http://get-spscripts.com/2011/02/add-sharepoint-or-ad-groupuser-to-all.html

I think you have to tweak it as per you requirement.